# Direct file link in liferay leads to odd login page

Tags: liferay

I have a link that downloads a file
https://example.com/documents/10157/68672/document_name.xlsx/375e0295-874e-4b9c-b155-6347bdc0c119

If I click this link on a browser where I'm logged in to liferay, a tab opens then closes instantly and the file downloads.

If I click the link in incognito mode or on another browser, it opens a new tab with a login page. This is good, obviously we only want authenticated users to get our files.

The problem is, on this page when you click `Sign In` with valid credentials entered, it just downloads the file without changing the page in any way. The login page stays there, with any error messages from the last login attempt. I can keep clicking the `Sign In` button to download the file over and over again.

Is this normal? Shouldn't the page either redirect to the landing page or close the tab once the file starts downloading? Is there some way to get the page to refresh when they log in?

Here's a screenshot after I successfully downloaded the file.

[image: Odd login page]

Answer (score 0):

You're using a deep link to obtain a file from the documents and media library, so I think is the behaviour you can expect.